# How to Iterate Input form with different value in Angular 5

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-forms

In my code, if i click the `add_box` icon, it will add another input form below so that I could input more values, but this is the problem shown in this link http://g.recordit.co/R0iifhd6Wd.gif

and this is my code

#### Component.ts

```js
instrumentsData = {
  particulars: ''
}

addParticular() {
  this.particulars.push('');
}
```

#### Component.html

```html
<div class="form-group">
<button (click)="addParticular()" class="button-box"><i class="material-icons">add_box</i></button>
   <ul class="form-fields" *ngFor="let particular of particulars">
       <li>
           <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="instrumentsData.particular">
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get this issue is you always bind 1 value in ngModel instrumentsData.particular

You could resolve your issue by doing like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
<button (click)="addParticular()" class="button-box"><i class="material-icons">add_box</i></button>
   <ul class="form-fields" *ngFor="let particular of particulars; index as i;trackBy: trackByFn">
       <li>
           <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="particulars[i]">
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Component.ts:

```
...
  particulars: any[] = [];

  addParticular() {
  this.particulars.push('');
  }

  trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index;
  }
...
```

Here is your plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/98mLfBla5KQqx4hpNne2?p=preview

Or it could be another array then you don't need trackBy in *ngFor

Answer (score 0):

the problem is simple. your are using the same ngModel for all your inputs, that's why you can see that behavior in your app

if particular is a array then you can do it like

```
<div class="form-group">
<button (click)="addParticular()" class="button-box"><i class="material-icons">add_box</i></button>
   <ul class="form-fields" *ngFor="let particular of particulars; let i= index">
       <li>
           <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="instrumentsData.particular[i]">
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```